# How to enable Full StackTraces in Unity 2021

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, memory-leaks

Today I got the message "A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak. Enable Full StackTraces..." How can I enable it in Unity 2021.3.18f?

All I know it should be enabled from "Jobs" menu, but full stack traces option is missing. I need to install some package from package manager which is also not available.

Any advise/clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StackTrace.html

Comment: It doesn't help. I still get the same notice.

Comment: Basically this means you are somewhere using a native array but don't `Dispose();` it when you don't need it anymore

Answer (score 1):

After some research it came out that "Jobs" menu is available in all Unity versions except 2021.*.*.

To install "Jobs", load following package "com.unity.jobs" from package manager via "Add package by name"